# How to work with NServiceBus in gateway mode

Tags: .net, nservicebus, gateway, servicebus

I've been trying to get the pubsub sample in the NServiceBus download to work in a gateway mode.

I haven't really been able to find out much detail at all about how to get NServiceBus to run in gateway mode.

How do I setup the publisher/server in gateway mode? When I did try I received an access denied exception which would either be due to the account I'm running it under or I'm missing something.

How do I setup the subscribers/clients to communicate to the gateway?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "gateway mode" - it is an additional process. You'd run one instance at each site.
Have you read the documentation?

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/gateway/

Comment: Yes I have, Udi. I am a bit confused by it. It would be nice if there was a tutorial on how to do it.

This is the process I have tried:
1. I've setup the gateway config URI to the server on both the client and the server.
2. Run the gateway host process on all machines. But the listen URI tells me the format of the network name is invalid for the client machines.

The rest of the process I assume is:
3. Started the server.
4. Started the client.
5. Messages will then be passed between the two over the specified HTTP port.

Comment: You've got it wrong at step 1. You can't have the gateway on the client listen on a server URL - it has to be a local endpoint.
To a large extent, the gateway is intended for multi-site server to server communication - not for communicating with clients over HTTP.